# Switch stretching top navbar

Tags: html, css

[Here](https://mtm828.github.io/index.html), I have a top navbar, it's all good but what ruined it was the dark mode switch, it's height is bigger than the links' heights, so the `<li>` elements look like they're stuck to the top of the bar. How can I resize the switch or stretch the other list items so they fit? Thank you for your time!
EDIT: I don't really want to cutt off the bottom by setting the height, that'll play about with the centering. I want to either stretch the others or squeeze the switch `<li>` element. Any further clarification necessary?

Comment: Please tell me what's wrong with the question. (눈‸눈)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add  line-height: 40px; to ul.topNav li a class

```
ul.topNav li a {
    color: white;
    padding: 14px;
    font-size: 175%;
    transition: color 1s;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Will this cut the bottom off, stretch the others or squeeze the switch?

Comment: its only add height to links to fit the navbar height and switch height etc not change

Comment: Oh OK, I might make this the accepted answer then. I'll wait for more answers.

Answer (score 1):

A super quick fix will be on `line 119` in the `CSS.css` you can change the `font-size: 175%;` to `font-size: 30px;`

**A side note:** if you are trying to make dark mode with a way more efficient way try reading about CSS variables and here is a use case for example
the `:root` contains all the colors and you use them where ever you want and because they are variable you can change them when you need

```css
:root {
  --dark-clr: #0a1229;
  --main-clr: #3b5ec9;
  --light-clr: #f9fbff;
  --white-clr: #fff;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.dark {
  background-color: var(--dark-clr);
}

.main {
  background-color: var(--main-clr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box main"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

now you can use the CSS built-in `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` which will make the variables change when the device has dark mode enabled try on your computer toggling the dark mode on and off and see the colors change

```css
:root {
  --dark-clr: #0a1229;
  --main-clr: #3b5ec9;
  --light-clr: #f9fbff;
  --white-clr: #fff;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { 
    :root{
        --dark-clr: #fff;
        --light-clr: #0a1229;
        --white-clr: #0a1229;
    }
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.dark {
  background-color: var(--dark-clr);
}

.white {
  background-color: var(--white-clr);
}

.light {
  background-color: var(--light-clr);
}

.main {
  background-color: var(--main-clr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box dark"></div>
  <div class="box light"></div>
  <div class="box white"></div>
  <div class="box main"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

hope this helps you achieve your goal

edit:
the only problem with the current code is that when you add a lot of elements and pages and different buttons and styles the CSS file will be huge and that will hurt the performance of the site.

Answer (score 0):

give an height attribute to all li
for example

```
ul li {
        height:80px ;
        }
```

add this between  tags

Comment: if that was helpful don't forget to vote :)

Comment: But wouldn't that just cut the bottom of the list item?

Comment: could you say what is exactly problem ?

Comment: See my edit, is it clear enough?

Comment: i think remove `margin-bottom:5px;` from your label styles , it will be completely center of the nav

Comment: that margin cause seems it's not in middle

Comment: Where is it exactly? The switch's `<label>` tag?